# How to unapply a migration in ASP.NET Core with EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2015

When I run `PM> Remove-Migration -context BloggingContext` in VS2015 with an ASP.NET Core project using EF Core, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The migration '20160703192724_MyFirstMigration' has already been applied to the database. Unapply it and try again. If the migration has been applied to other databases, consider reverting its changes using a new migration.
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.RemoveMigration(String projectDir, String rootNamespace, Boolean force) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.RemoveMigration(String contextType, Boolean force) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsRemoveCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0() 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) 
The migration '20160703192724_MyFirstMigration' has already been applied to the database. Unapply it and try again. If the migration has been applied to other databases, consider reverting its changes using a new migration.
```

How can I unapply it? I'm using latest release of ASP.NET Core 1.0, EF Core, and VS2015 Update 3.

Comment: try adding `-force` at the end

Comment: The article https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations#reversing-a-migration describes the steps. Thanks [@drewskis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8304027/drewskis) for the link

Answer (score 530):

Use:

**CLI**

`> dotnet ef database update <previous-migration-name>`

**Package Manager Console**

`PM> Update-Database <previous-migration-name>`

Example:

`PM> Update-Database MyInitialMigration`

Then try to remove last migration.

Removing migration without database update doesn't work because you applied changes to database.

If using PMC, Try:
PM> update-database 0
This will wipe the database and allow you to remove the Migration Snapshot on your Solution

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I first used `dotnet ef database update MyFirstMigration --context BloggingContext` that worked successfully. Then I ran `dotnet ef migrations remove --context BloggingContext` that gave me the same error message as in my post

Comment: You'll need to update to the migration before `MyFirstMigration`. If that is the 1st migration (as the name implies) then you can use `dotnet ef database update 0` to revert(unapply) all migrations from the database. You should then be able to run `dotnet ef migrations remove`.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that you should only use the name of the migration, excluding the date-prefix

Comment: Call `dotnet ef migrations remove` after this

Comment: Your second statement: "Then try to remove last migration" is not complete in this answer, please say exactly what you mean. remove the migration file? execute a command? ...

Comment: Your mistake is to try to delete/remove the very same migration as the one to which you've upgraded your database last. You can't delete a migration that's still applied (i.e. current level of the database). You can only remove that migration after you've updated your database to the last migration BEFORE that one. Therefore, you must first update your database to <previous-migration-name> (using the command he gave you) and then when you call "dotnet ef migrations remove" it implicitly deletes the LAST one, i.e. MyFirstMigration.

Comment: @nam Its about "LastGoodMigration" not last migration.

Answer (score 291):

**To unapply a specific migration(s)**:

```
dotnet ef database update LastGoodMigrationName
or
PM> Update-Database -Migration LastGoodMigrationName
```

**To unapply all migrations**:

```
dotnet ef database update 0
or
PM> Update-Database -Migration 0
```

**To remove last migration:**

```
dotnet ef migrations remove
or
PM> Remove-Migration
```

**To remove all migrations:**

just remove `Migrations` folder.

**To remove last few migrations (not all):**

There is no a command to remove a bunch of migrations and we can't just remove these few `migrations` and their `*.designer.cs` files since we need to keep the snapshot file in the consistent state.  We need to remove migrations one by one (see `To remove last migration` above).

**To unapply and remove last migration:**

```
dotnet ef migrations remove --force
or
PM> Remove-Migration -Force
```

Comment: I keep seeing the word `unapply` all over these posts.  It just hit me it's not a technical term, it's the word `un - apply`

Comment: I wonder what is the method "down" used for ?

Comment: While viewing folder named `Migrations` in my Visual Studio IDE, and running above commands in my Package Manager Console, it would be super useful if this answer would state the expected results. For example, does removing effect the contents of the Migrations folder? That is, should the files resulting from an `Add-Migration` be removed, or do they remain and I need to remove them manually?? Thanks!

Comment: dotnet ef migrations remove --force worked for me in ef core

Comment: @Pajri Aprilio When you remove a migration, the 'down' part lists the steps necessary to undo said migration.

Comment: The command "Remove-Migration -Force" works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 184):

To completely remove all migrations and start all over again, do the following:

```
dotnet ef database update 0
dotnet ef migrations remove
```

Comment: But you don't want to remove all migrations. For example,  you want to keep the default migration VS creates for identity (User Accounts) under Data\Migrations folder.

Comment: It's good to know `dotnet ef database update 0`, but running `dotnet ef migrations remove` afterwards will remove default migration for Identity, which might not be desired.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `dotnet ef database update 0`! I hadn't seen this mentioned anywhere...

Comment: @nam "But you don't want to remove all migrations." But some of us do. Don't assume what I want :)

Comment: This didn't work for me. The first line was ok and remove all the migrations, on the second line I still get `The migration '20180618103514_InitialMigration' has already been applied to the database. Revert it and try again. If the migration has been applied to other databases, consider reverting its changes using a new migration.`

Comment: is there any way to do it in the run-time programmaticaly (e.g. using `dbContext.GetService<IMigrator>()`)??

Comment: Can I do that from the PM console?

Comment: @ShimmyWeitzhandler Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55323154/109941

Comment: I was trying to remove the very first and sole migration I made and the '0' parameter helped :)

Answer (score 76):

To revert the last applied migration you should:

1. Revert migration from database:

   - `PM> Update-Database <prior-migration-name>`
   - `PS/cmd> dotnet ef database update <prior-migration-name>`
2. If you call `dbContext.Database.Migrate()`/`MigrateAsync()` in `Main`/`Startup`: remove the latest migration file from project (or it will be reapplied again on next step)
3. Update model snapshot:

   - `PM> Remove-Migration`
   - `PS/cmd> dotnet ef migrations remove`

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly
Fascinated that out of all the solutions no one ever mentioned the need for step 2.

Comment: Yeh, Nobody mentioned the step two.Thank you

Comment: not sure about the second step, in my case(latest VS2017) the migration file will be deleted automatically after calling `Remove-Migration` without problem. I'm not sure what you said "it will be reapplied again on next step"!

Comment: @S.Serpooshan Indeed. I manually deleted it but when I ran Remove-Migration it complained about my previous migration having been applied to the database. But, it works.

Comment: The second step I think is only necessary if you call `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` in your startup.cs

Answer (score 57):

You can still use the `Update-Database` command.

```
Update-Database -Migration <migration name> -Context <context name>
```

However, judging by the name of your migration i'm assuming it's the first migration so that command may not work.  You should be able to delete the entry from the `__MigrationHistory` table in your database and then run the `Remove-Migration` command again.  You could also delete the migration file and just start again.

Comment: You can call `Update-Database` from Package Management Console or call `dotnet ef database update` from the command prompt from the project directory.

Comment: Just to clarify Brad's answer here - `<migration name>` should be the name of the migration you want to *go back to* (i.e. probably the migration *before* the one you screwed up), not the name of the migration you want to undo.

Answer (score 45):

You should delete migration **'20160703192724_MyFirstMigration'** record from  **'_EFMigrationsHistory'** table.

**otherwise** below command will remove migration and delete migrations folder:

**PMC Command:**

```
   > remove-migration -force
```

**CLI Command:**

```
   > dotnet ef migrations remove -f
```

[Link About CLI Commands](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/cli-commands-for-ef-core-migration.aspx)

[Link About PMC Commands](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/pmc-commands-for-ef-core-migration.aspx#remove-migration)

Comment: Worked for me .NET6.  When using plain Remove-Migration, the framework first added it to the database and then refused to remove the migration because it was in the database.  So, after Update-Database <good_migration_name>, use the Remove-Migration -force and it does what's requried including the model snapshot.

Answer (score 39):

Simply you can target a Migration by value

```
 Update-Database -Migration:0
```

Then go ahead and remove it

```
 Remove-Migration
```

**NOTE** this is for when you want to clear database.

Comment: This worked for me but I'm using EF and .NET core 2.0 with VS2017

Comment: Watch out: -Migration:0 means go back to the state with no migrations. This will clear your database

Comment: Yes according to the question asked. You can increment the value depending on the migration you want to roll back to

Comment: Workin in .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 21):

##### A summary of everything you need to know

*All the commands will be written using `dotnet`.*

*This solution is provided for .net Core 3.1, but should be compatible with next versions as well*

#### Removing migrations:

- Removing a migration deletes the file from your project
- Removing a migration can only be done, if the migration is not applied to the database
  yet
- To remove last created migration: `cd to_your_project` then `dotnet ef migrations remove`

**Note: Removing a migration works only, if you didn't execute yet `dotnet ef database update` or called in your c# code `Database.Migrate()`, in other words, only if the migration is not applied to your database yet.**

#### Unapplying migrations (revert migrations):

- Removes unwanted changes from the database
- Does not delete the migration file from your project, but allows you to remove it after unapplying
- To revert a migration, you can either:

  - Create a new migration `dotnet ef migrations add <your_changes>` and apply it, which is recommended by microsoft.
  - Or, update your database to a specified migration (which is basically unapplying or reverting the non chosen migrations) with `dotnet ef database update <your_migration_name_to_jump_back_to>`

**Note: If you choose to reverse a migration but the specific column or table involved is already present and being used in your database, this action will remove that column or table entirely. As a result, you will lose any data stored in them.**

*After reverting the migration, you can remove your unwanted migration*

Comment: In your last note, I think you wanted to say: "if the destination migration you want to have after un-appling a migration, does not contain..."
or
"if the migration you want to un-apply to, does not contain"

Answer (score 13):

In Package Manager Console:

`Update-Database Your_Migration_You_Want_To_Revert_To`

[More options and explanation on how to revert migrations can be seen here](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations#reversing-a-migration)

Comment: Useful link, should be a comment of the question

Comment: This is what you want to use in .NET core

Answer (score 11):

As the question itself deals with a first migration this answer is for anyone who is here looking for way to revert their last migration since most answers do not cover the alternate scenarios (For most of us it's not our first migration and we cannot wipe the entire migration history).

These commands are for **Package Manager Console**.

Let's say you have the following migrations in your code:

- 20220110_InitialMigration
- 20200210_GoodMigration
- 20200210_LastGoodMigration
- 20200210_BadMigration
- 20200210_BadMigrationAgain

**If you have already applied the migration to the db like in the question**

1. Run:

   `Update-Database -Migration <Last_Good_Migration_Name>`

   Note: The name should be without date prefix. Eg: `Update-Database -Migration LastGoodMigration`
2. Then to remove the bad migration run:

   `Remove-Migration`

   Note: Since we have two bad migrations run the `Remove Migration` command twice.

**If you haven't applied the migration to the db**

Just run:

`Remove-Migration`

In our case run the `Remove Migration` command twice.

Hope this helps someone.

**UPDATE August 2023**

If you have multiple db contexts add `-Context Context_Name` to each command. For example:
`Remove-Migration -Context MyDbContext`

Answer (score 10):

In general if you are using the Package Manager Console the right way to remove a specific Migration is by referencing the name of the migration

```
Update-Database -Migration {Name of Migration} -Context {context}
```

Another way to remove the last migration you have applied according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-remove) is by using the command:

```
dotnet ef migrations remove
```

This command should be executed from the developer command prompt ([how to open command prompt](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-2618089)) inside your solution directory.

For example if your application is inside name "Application" and is in the folder c:\Projects. Then your path should be:

```
C:\Projects\Application
```

Comment: The question was what to do if `dotnet ef migrations remove' returns an error "The migration has already been applied to the database"

Answer (score 9):

In order to unapply a migration in EF Core 1.0 use the command:

```
dotnet ef database update {migration_name}
```

Use the migration name of the migration until which you would like to preserve your changes. The list of names of the migration can be found using:

```
dotnet ef migrations list
```

Answer (score 8):

To "unapply" the most (recent?) migration after it has already been applied to the database:

1. Open the SQL Server Object Explorer (View -> "SQL Server Object Explorer")
2. Navigate to the database that is linked to your project by expanding the small triangles to the side.
3. Expand "Tables"
4. Find the table named "dbo._EFMigrationsHistory".
5. Right click on it and select "View Data" to see the table entries in Visual Studio.
6. Delete the row corresponding to your migration that you want to unapply (Say "yes" to the warning, if prompted).
7. Run "dotnet ef migrations remove" again in the command window in the directory that has the project.json file. Alternatively, run "Remove-Migration" command in the package manager console.

Hope this helps and is applicable to any migration in the project... I tested this out only to the most recent migration...

Happy coding!

Comment: This will not actually un-apply the migration, just make the framework "think" it has not been applied. Your database will be in an inconsistent state if you do this.

Comment: Manually editing the data in your __EFMigrationsHistory is terrible advice.  Don't do it.  That table is only meant to be used under-the-hood by the migration tools.  If you start manually editing the data, a single mistake can create all kinds of crazy unexpected behavior in your project.  It's a much better idea to use one of the other recommended solutions.

Comment: We had a situation where a junior team member got confused with switching branches, and ended up deleting the migration manually from both (although it was still in the __EFMigrationsHistory table since it was already applied), so we lost the "down." This is what we ended up having to do, plus some manual reversals in SSMS. So don't do it - unless you have no other choice at this point. At least all he did was add a single new field.

Answer (score 8):

To revert all the migrations which are applied to DB simply run:

```
update-database 0
```

It should be followed with running `Remove-Migration` as many times as there are migration files visible in the Migration directory. The command deletes the latest migration and also updates the snapshot.

Answer (score 8):

```
dotnet ef database update <the-migration-you-want-to-recover>
dotnet ef migrations remove
```

Don't forget the remove-Call since this will remove the migration files for you and update the Snapshot-file.

Comment: Did you really mean `database remove` or did you mean `migrations remove`?

Answer (score 3):

at first run the following command :

```
PM>update-database -migration:0
```

and then run this one :

```
PM>remove_migration
```

Finish

Answer (score 2):

**Removing a Migration**

You can remove the last migration if it is not applied to the database. Use the following remove commands to remove the last created migration files and revert the model snapshot.

Package Manager Console

PM> remove-migration

CLI> dotnet ef migrations remove

The above commands will remove the last migration and revert the model snapshot to the previous migration. Please note that if a migration is already applied to the database, then it will throw the following exception.

The migration  has already been applied to the database. Revert it and try again. If the migration has been applied to other databases, consider reverting its changes using a new migration.

**Reverting a Migration**

Suppose you changed your domain class and created the second migration named MySecondMigration using the add-migration command and applied this migration to the database using the Update command. But, for some reason, you want to revert the database to the previous state. In this case, use the update-database  command to revert the database to the specified previous migration snapshot.

Package Manager Console

PM> Update-database MyFirstMigration

**CLI**

> dotnet ef database update MyFirstMigration.

The above command will revert the database based on a migration named MyFirstMigration and remove all the changes applied for the second migration named MySecondMigration. This will also remove MySecondMigration entry from the __EFMigrationsHistory table in the database.

Note: This will not remove the migration files related to MySecondMigration. Use the remove commands to remove them from the project.

Answer (score 2):

Because I've been redirected to this question for searching about roll back migration in `ef` not `ef core`, I'm adding this answer to the question for everybody who want to know about the same problem in `ef`. If you're using `ef` you can use the following command to roll back the migration:

```
Update-Database [[-Migration] <String>] 
                [-Context <String>]
                [-Project <String>]
                [-StartupProject <String>] 
                [<CommonParameters>]
```

Based on question:

```
Update-Database -Migration <previous-migration-name> -context BloggingContext
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try using -force parameter. So the final command would looks like :

```
Remove-Migration -force
```

[image: VS Package Manager Console]

Answer (score -1):

1.find table "dbo._EFMigrationsHistory", then delete the migration record that you want to remove.
2. run "remove-migration" in PM(Package Manager Console).
Works for me.

Comment: This will lead to an inconsistent state of the database (e.g. a column is already dropped)