# EFCore SQLite database substitutes its own table name for mine

Tags: sqlite, ef-core-3.1

I'm building a .Net Core 3.1 desktop application using EFCore 3.1 and the SQLite provider.

My problem is that the SQLite Provider keeps throwing an exception, telling me that table `ValidationTargetTypes2`  does not exist.  But I'm not using that table name in my queries.  I'm using `ValidationTargetTypes`  (Note the lack of "2" suffix). And that table ***does*** exist.

I turned on logging and it verifies that the correct table name is being used.  Here is the complete log output of my SQL Command.  Note that  I only use the correct table name `ValidationTargetTypes`.  But the exception still complains that `ValidationTargetTypes2` not existing

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__target_Serial_0='A500' (Size = 4)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "v"."Id", "v"."FileName", "v"."IsDeleted", "v"."Name", "v"."Serial", "v"."ValidationTargetTypeId"
FROM "ValidationTargets" AS "v"
WHERE NOT ("v"."IsDeleted") AND ("v"."Serial" = @__target_Serial_0)
LIMIT 1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__target_Part_0='RSP-VC01' (Size = 8)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "v"."Id", "v"."Name", "v"."Part"
FROM "ValidationTargetTypes" AS "v"
WHERE "v"."Part" = @__target_Part_0
LIMIT 2
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p0='ValidationTarget_RSP-VC01_A500' (Size = 30), @p1='False' (DbType = String), @p2='A500' (Size = 4), @p3='A500' (Nullable = false) (Size = 4), @p4='1' (DbType = String)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO "ValidationTargets" ("FileName", "IsDeleted", "Name", "Serial", "ValidationTargetTypeId")
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);
SELECT "Id"
FROM "ValidationTargets"
WHERE changes() = 1 AND "rowid" = last_insert_rowid();
```

And here, is the error that then immediately appears.  Note the substituted table name.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update: Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'GelSight.Mobile.Data.GelSightContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: main.ValidationTargetTypes2'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
```

Somewhere, somehow that wrong table name with the "2" suffix is being substituted.  Where can it be happening?  Nowhere in my entire codebase does the string `ValidationTargetTypes2` even appear.  I searched every file type ("*.*") for that string.  Nope.

Also nowhere in the actual live database do I see anything by that name.

If I delete the database file and re-run my app (which calls Migrate at startup to ensure it exists), then the query works just fine.  So I guess the problem must be within the database file.

I've had about 4 migrations on this database.  Clearly I've caused this problem.  At one point I did briefly have a table by that name (with the "2" suffix) because I had to [work around a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61683088/how-do-i-remove-most-recent-efcore-migration-when-sqlite-provider-cannot-drop-co)  caused by the fact that Sqlite cannot drop columns.  I followed [Microsoft recommendations fixing](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723262) it. 
 But clearly my temporary rename has left some detritus around.  The question is, where?

Is there any way for me to edit this database manually to fix this?  I really hope to avoid deleting it. 
 I don't know where in the database to go.  I don't see anything in the MigrationHistory that stands out

Comment: I should say I finally just gave up and wiped all my migrations and started over.  Which means that my clients need to start over with a new database  That's acceptable at this stage in my development but it would still be nice to know if there was a way to diagnose this or what could be causing it.

Comment: Yes, the workings of EF are mysterious.  That's why I hate frameworks that work with magic.