# How remove particular migration from migration folder in asp.net ef core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using `asp.net` `ef core` and I have to remove specific `migration` from the `migration folder`. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unapply a migration in ASP.NET Core with EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192450/how-to-unapply-a-migration-in-asp-net-core-with-ef-core)

Comment: That example not working

Comment: What do you mean by specific in your question ? The last one, the first one or one that is applied after a lot migrations are done ?

Answer (score 2):

If u wanna delete your last migration after applying it to database use

> Remove-Migration -Force

Or if u want to delete any particular migration then use

> Remove-Migration "YourMigrationName" -Force

This worked for me.

Note : Be carefull and sure while removing any particular migration cz it might affect your database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last migration type

> Remove-Migration

from Visual Studio Powershell
or

> dotnet ef migrations remove

from the .NET Core CLI

[.NET Documentation Managing Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

This is for EF version 6.0.10

You can get a list of migrations by typing

> Get-Migration

Or `dotnet ef migrations list` from the CLI

Answer (score 0):

If U Wanna Deleted Your Last Migration You Can Use
**Remove-Migration**
but if you get this error
**The migration *Your Migration Name* has already been applied to the database. **
this mean you use **Update-Database** and your migration add in database so if you wanna delete this migration you should find migration table in you Database and delete from migration table and delete any table you don't need that. and again use
**Remove-Database** and this will work.

> If your data isn't big so you can use this but be careful maybe your data you had save
> will delete ....