# How to revert the first "update-database" of a EF Core Project?

Tags: entity-framework-core

When I started a new EF Core project and wanner to create a new database, I made a mistake that wrote a wrong database name in connection string. Then I ran `add-migration` and `update-database`. And then I found the migration had applied to an existing database.

I attempted to revert this apply. But it's the first migration script of project. I don't know how to revert.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192450/how-to-unapply-a-migration-in-asp-net-core-with-ef-core#:~:text=To%20revert%20the%20last%20applied,snapshot%3A%20PM%3E%20Remove%2DMigration

Comment: Thank but the migration I want to revert is the first, there's not a "prior-migration-name" to run update-database.

Answer (score 1):

I had founded the answer: just run `update-database -migration:0`. That could revert the frist applied migration. Then the first migration script would be able to be removed.