# Save datagrid information to text file shows an empty file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have code that allows you to save datagrid information in visual studio into a text file but the datagrid is filled out and it just shows nothing in the  text file

Code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.FileName = "untitled.txt";
        sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
        sfd.Filter = "txt files (*.text) |*.txt*";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Stream fileStream = sfd.OpenFile();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

            for(int i = 0; i <  dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++) //rows
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) // columns
                {
                    sw.Write("\t", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
                }
                sw.WriteLine("");
            }
            sw.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Are come columns maybe null?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unapply a migration in ASP.NET Core with EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192450/how-to-unapply-a-migration-in-asp-net-core-with-ef-core)

Comment: @AliSalehi did you comment on the wrong question?

Comment: The data is written to the database, and the dataGridView1 control is bound to the database to obtain data.

Answer (score 0):

In my small tests, it appears the “\t” is getting misinterpreted. Fortunately, a simple fix is to simply make a Tab `string` and use it like…

```
string tab = "\t";
```

Then…

```
sw.Write( tab + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + tab + "|");
```

In addition, it is a good idea to implement `using` statements to ensure the resources get closed and disposed of properly. Something like…

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog()) {
    sfd.FileName = "untitled.txt";
    sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
    sfd.Filter = "txt files (*.text) |*.txt*";
    string tab = "\t";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      using (Stream fileStream = sfd.OpenFile()) {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream)) {
          for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
            if (!dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow) {
              for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
                sw.Write(tab + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                if (j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) {
                  sw.Write(tab + "|");
                }
              }
              sw.WriteLine("");
            }
          }
          //sw.Close();
          //fileStream.Close();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do i remove the extra "|" at the end of the row in the text file its not supposed to be  there shown in this text file "txt|txt|txt|"

Comment: Please see the edit. You may want to consider using a third party CSV library. CSVHelper is one option and it may make things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNamespaceGoesHere
{
    public static class DataGridViewExtensions
    {
        public static void ExportRows(this DataGridView sender, string fileName, string defaultNullValue = "(empty)")
        {
            File.WriteAllLines(fileName, (sender.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Where(row => !row.IsNewRow)
                .Select(row => new {
                    row,
                    rowItem = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                        .ToArray(), c => ((c.Value == null) ? defaultNullValue : c.Value.ToString())))
                })
                .Select(@row => @row.rowItem)));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (replace the file name from your SaveFileDialog)

```
private void ExportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ExportRows("data1.txt");
}
```